# Response from Google Cloud Messaging Server is OK, but Response Body says "Unrecognized IP address"

Tags: c#, google-cloud-messaging

Response from Google cloud messaging server is "OK", but the body of response says "You have browsed from an unrecognized IP address. The proxy therefore denied access to this site or page:"

```
    private static  string SendGCMNotification(string apiKey, string postData, string postDataContentType = "application/json")
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

        //
        //  MESSAGE CONTENT
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        //
        //  CREATE REQUEST
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        Request.Method = "POST";
        Request.KeepAlive = false;
        Request.ContentType = postDataContentType;
        Request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", apiKey));
        Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36";
        Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        //
        //  SEND MESSAGE
        try
        {
            WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();
            HttpStatusCode ResponseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)Response).StatusCode;
            if (ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
            {
                var text = "Unauthorized - need new token";
            }
            else if (!ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
            {
                var text = "Response from web service isn't OK";
            }

            StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
            string responseLine = Reader.ReadToEnd();
            Reader.Close();

            return responseLine;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return "error";
    }

    public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add any Restriction for your Server Key?

Answer (score 0):

Take note of this statement from [Implementing an HTTP Connection Server](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http):

> If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or
>   from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with
>   GCM in order for your GCM client apps to receive messages. The ports
>   to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only uses 5228, but
>   it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide specific IPs, so
>   you should allow your firewall to accept outgoing connections to all
>   IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in Google's ASN of
>   15169.